# Facebook access tokens, permissions and offline publish_actions

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-access-token

I am working on an app where one of the things that I want to do is publish a status on behalf of a user, offline. That is when the user is not using the app. The facebook's documentation is not clear about validity of access tokens, type of access token required for particular call(like publish stream), how to renew it, etc. I am using PHP Facebook SDK. It has a function `setExtendedAccessToken()`. But it is for extending the short-lived access token obtained by the client side for 60days(with some exception cases ofcourse). What if I have a long-lived access token that I obtained via server-to-server call. More specifically, by calling the `$facebook->getAccessToken()` method. I am using the following code to post in offline mode.

```
$req =  array(
'access_token' => $access_token, //stored in db, obtained thru getAccessToken()
'name' => "Awesome Status!",
'link' => "apps.facebook.com/myapp",
'description' => "Some Description",
'picture'=>"xxx.jpg",
'caption' => "Caption this"
);
$res = $facebook->api("/$userid/feed", 'POST', $req);
```

Thanks!

**Addition:**

Tried using `setExtendedAccessToken` function, but it doesn't change anything. I even checked the access tokens information [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/). I think it works for with the short-lived, client side generated token.

Comment: You are aware that you are not allowed to publish content that the users did not create themselves actively, right?

Comment: What? No offence, but either my english is bad or urs. Not able to understand what you mean by that. I hv myself written the code. So???

Comment: @emotionull Surely your english is not quite good.

Comment: I’m just saying that it looks like you want to post stuff to the user’s wall automatically, without the user being involved in the process of _creating_ that content – and that’s not allowed by platform policies. (If that’s not the case, and the user is active on your site while creating stuff themselves, then you should also be able to get a current access token every time, so you wouldn’t have to ask for a long-lived one or even offline access …)

Comment: _"What if I have a long-lived access token that I obtained via server-to-server call. "_ - then you don't need to extend it, because it is long-lived already.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the **App Access Token** `(APP_ID|APP_SECRET)` to publish on behalf of the user offline; once the user has authorized your app.

Comment: No. That requires a User Access Token.

Comment: No, you can use App access token once the user has auth app for this action

Comment: How can I convince you? Can you give any link to any doc page? I know the documentation is pretty much sketchy.

Comment: You dont need to convince me, but yourself. See here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/ , you'll find that: `App access tokens can also be used to publish content to Facebook on behalf of a person who has granted an open graph publishing permission to your application.`

Comment: You can test the same using Graph API Explorer too. PS, dont forget to accept the ans if helped!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts. But it giving this error "OAuthException: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action"

Comment: So, that's what I said - `once the user has authorized your app.`; the user must have granted publish_stream (or publish_action if using OG) to the App